# Finite dimensional irreps of $p$-adic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups, p-adic-numbers

What are some examples of finite dimensional irreducible complex representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

One knows such a representations cannot be smooth, so probably the examples will be contrived, but so be it.

Comment: Well, there are some obvious $p$-adic reps of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ (namely $Sym^n$ of the standard rep); now choose an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ into $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: See an answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259491/irreducible-representations-of-simple-complex-groups

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Is it obvious that these representations stay irreducible after applying the embedding?

Comment: @Spinoza yes — the reps are irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Now the Lemma you need is that irreducibility is preserved under extensions of algebraically closed fields.